# Excel VBA Macro - Loop Through Sheets & Clear Rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to get this macro to loop through all sheets within a workbook & then filter & clear some cells.. the loop works when I do not have the filter/clear cells part of the macro enabled however as soon as I uncomment the filter & clear part of the macro, the macro will only filter and clear the cells within the Active Sheet, any ideas where I am going wrong?

Any help very much appreciated!

```
Sub MovethroughWB()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets 'This statement starts the loop
        If ws.Name <> "Exclusions" Then 'Exclude this sheet from the loop
            Range("D2:J2").Select
            Selection.AutoFilter
            ActiveSheet.Range("$D$2:$J$200").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>#N/A", _
                Operator:=xlAnd
            Range("D3:J200").Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Selection.ClearContents
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `ws` as a sheet variable for the loop, but then it is not used to qualify your `Range`s (so it assumes `ActiveSheet`) and then later you are explicitly using `ActiveSheet` instead of `ws` for some reason.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I've tried to put "ws.Range("D2:J2").Select" but I just get "Select method of Range class failed"

Comment: @Jonathan don't use `.Select` see the link I posted. work directly with the range like `ws.Range("D2:J2").AutoFilter`. Using `.Select` is a extremely bad pratice and comes with a lot of unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Referce a worksheet for **every** object that is located in a worksheet (`Range`, `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows`, etc)
2. Stop using `.Select` ([How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)).

And your code gets reliable:

```
Sub MovethroughWB()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets 'This statement starts the loop
        If ws.Name <> "Exclusions" Then 'Exclude this sheet from the loop
            ws.Range("D2:J2").AutoFilter
            ws.Range("$D$2:$J$200").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Operator:=xlAnd
            ws.Range("D3:J200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```